# FTP Illegal PORT command

Tags: ftp, proftpd

I've set up proftpd to use ssl/tls. Trying to connect I get an 'Illegal PORT command'

```
Finding Host xxx.nl ...
Connecting to xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:21
Connected to xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:21 in 0.018001 seconds, Waiting for Server 
Response
Initializing SSL Session ...
220 FTP Server ready.
AUTH TLS
234 AUTH TLS successful
SSL session NOT set for reuse
SSL Session Started.
Host type (1): AUTO
USER xxx
331 Password required for xxx
PASS (hidden)
230 User xxx logged in
SYST
215 UNIX Type: L8
Host type (2): Unix (Standard)
PBSZ 0
200 PBSZ 0 successful
PROT P
200 Protection set to Private
PWD
257 "/" is the current directory
CWD /var/www/html/
250 CWD command successful
PWD257 "/var/www/html/" is the current directory
TYPE A
200 Type set to A
PORT 192,168,192,14,211,181
500 Illegal PORT command
Port failed 500 Illegal PORT command
PASV
227 Entering Passive Mode (xxx,xxx,xxx,xxx,160,151).
connecting data channel to xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:160,151(41111)
Failed to connect data channel to xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:160,151(41111)
```

iptables:

```
Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination
ACCEPT     icmp --  anywhere             anywhere            /* 000 accept all icmp */
ACCEPT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere            /* 001 accept all to lo interface */
REJECT     all  --  anywhere             loopback/8          /* 002 reject local traffic not on loopback interface */ reject-with icmp-port-unreachable
ACCEPT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere            /* 003 accept all to eth1 interface */
ACCEPT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere            /* 004 accept related established rules */ state RELATED,ESTABLISHED
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere            multiport ports ftp /* 021 allow ftp. */
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere            multiport ports ssh /* 022 allow ssh. */
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere            multiport ports smtp /* 025 allow smtp. */
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere            multiport ports pharos /* 051 allow rundeck. */
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere            multiport ports 8140 /* 814 allow puppetserver. */
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere            multiport ports http /* 080 allow http. */
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere            multiport ports https /* 443 allow https. */
DROP       all  --  anywhere             anywhere            /* 999 drop all */

Chain FORWARD (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination
```

Connecting via normal ftp works just fine...

I'm using WS_FTP with ftp-authssl//xxx.nl/.... I tried several other connection options, ports, etc. But all give the same error. Althoiugh it seems that sometimes a first directory listing is shown (but that might be caching of WS_FTP)